# Bold and very small text looks fuzzy

Tags: html, css, styled-components

[image]

[image]

Recently when using Serif font I have been having this problem where the text looks very fuzzy and not sharp.

What i've tried:

```css
  filter: blur(0.000001px);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

I am using, [Crimson Text](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Crimson+Text?query=crimson) from google fonts. On the preview it looks perfectly fine but when I put it in my site its all fuzzy.

I have looked for solutions everywhere but to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT :**

Here is the problematic file I presume.

```css
export const TopicCycleWrapper = styled.div`
  height: 80vh;
  max-width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* align-items: left; */
  justify-content: center;

  /* display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 13%; */

  /* -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; */
`;
export const InnerWrapper = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
`;

export const Primary = styled((props) => <Link {...props} />)`
  font-weight: ${(props) => props.theme.weight.bold};
  font-size: 80px;
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.primary};
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: #414141;
  }
`;

export const Secondary = styled.span`
  font-size: 60px;
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.secondary};
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export const Desc = styled.p`
  font-size: 20px;
`;
```

Here is my theme.js

```json
export const light = {
  fonts: { main: "Crimson Text, serif", code: "Roboto Mono, monospaced" },
  colors: {
    // theme === "dark" ? "test" : "no",
    main1: "#4d9ee0",
    main2: "#e5f1fa",
    dark1: "#1e1e1f",
    dark2: "#414244",
    dark3: "#a1a2a5",
    light1: "#F9FAFB", //f7f7f7
    light2: "#fcfcfc",

    primary: "#000",
    secondary: "#C8C8C8",
  },
  breakpoints: {
    mobile: "only screen and (max-width: 50rem)",
    tablet: "only screen and (max-width: 65rem)",
  },
  spacings: {
    xxSmall: ".25rem",
    xSmall: ".5rem",
    small: "1rem",
    medium: "2rem",
    large: "3rem",
    xLarge: "4rem",
    xxLarge: "6rem",
  },

  weight: {
    regular: "400",
    semiBold: "600",
    bold: "700",
    black: "900",
  },

  animations: { button: "box-shadow 0.3s ease", link: "color 0.2s ease" },
  shadows: { shadow: "0px 5px 20px rgba(30,30,31,0.05)" },
};
```

I am also using gatsby-plugin-google-fonts, I'm not sure if this is contributing to the problem

```json
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [
          `roboto mono`,
          `Crimson Text\:400, 400i, 600, 600i, 700, 700i, 900`, // you can also specify font weights and styles
        ],
        display: "swap",
      },
    },
```

Comment: please post a minimal reproduction setup

Comment: thats difficult because im using styled components with gatsby but ill add css edit